# spark data frame compare and show only values that are different

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have 2 dataframes to be compared and am using except to show the data present in first dataset and missing in the second.Its works fine i want to display only the values that are different instead of entire row so its easy for someone to identify the fields having difference .

**BELOW IS THE CODE SNIPPET**

```
 val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test6").getOrCreate();

  val schemaOrig = List( StructField("key",StringType,true)
    ,StructField("name",StringType,true)
    ,StructField("start_ts",TimestampType,true)
    ,StructField("txn_dt",StringType,true))

  val df =  spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("1","john",java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-16 00:00:00"),"2020-02-14")))
    ,StructType(schemaOrig))

  val df2 =  spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("1","andrew",java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2017-10-16 00:00:00"),"2020-02-14")))
    ,StructType(schemaOrig))

  df.except(df2).show(true)

+---+----+-------------------+----------+
|key|name|           start_ts|    txn_dt|
+---+----+-------------------+----------+
|  1|john| 2018-10-16 00:00:00 2020-02-14                 |
+---+----+-------------------+----------+
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
+---+-------------+--------------------+
|key|diff columns |     diff values 
+---+----------------------------------+
 1   name,txn_dt      john,2018-10-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can you add expected output ?

Comment: updated for expected output basically i hve a huge dataset with more than 100 columns in so showing entire row in an email is cumbersome. so just want to limit the data displayed

Comment: if you are sending result in mail, above your expected output show horizontal if you have more columns , instead you can send diff column & its value in this format ---------------------------------------------
|key  |   column    |  value                   |
---------------------------------------------
|1    |   name      |  john                    |
|1    |   start_ts  |  2018-10-16 00:00:00     |
---------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `full outer join` & extracting not matched columns.

Please check below code.

```
scala> dfa.printSchema
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- txn_dt: string (nullable = true)


scala> dfa.show(false)
+---+----+-------------------+----------+
|key|name|start_ts           |txn_dt    |
+---+----+-------------------+----------+
|1  |john|2018-10-16 00:00:00|2020-02-14|
+---+----+-------------------+----------+


scala> dfb.printSchema
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- txn_dt: string (nullable = true)


scala> dfb.show(false)
+---+------+-------------------+----------+
|key|name  |start_ts           |txn_dt    |
+---+------+-------------------+----------+
|1  |andrew|2017-10-16 00:00:00|2020-02-14|
+---+------+-------------------+----------+


scala> val diff_cols = dfa.columns.filterNot(_ == "key").map(c => when(dfa(c) =!= dfb(c),c))
diff_cols: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN (NOT (name = name)) THEN name END, CASE WHEN (NOT (start_ts = start_ts)) THEN start_ts END, CASE WHEN (NOT (txn_dt = txn_dt)) THEN txn_dt END)

scala> val diff_values = dfa.columns.filterNot(_ == "key").map(c => when(dfa(c) =!= dfb(c),dfa(c)))
diff_values: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN (NOT (name = name)) THEN name END, CASE WHEN (NOT (start_ts = start_ts)) THEN start_ts END, CASE WHEN (NOT (txn_dt = txn_dt)) THEN txn_dt END)

scala> dfa.join(dfb,dfa("key") === dfb("key"),"full").select(dfa("key"),concat_ws(",",diff_cols:_*).as("diff_columns"),concat_ws(",",diff_values:_*).as("diff_values")).show(false) // using full join & taking diff columns & values.
+---+-------------+------------------------+
|key|diff_columns |diff_values             |
+---+-------------+------------------------+
|1  |name,start_ts|john,2018-10-16 00:00:00|
+---+-------------+------------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: great,thnx ll try it out